# Помогите сделать кнопку css html js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Смотрите пример сразу. Не знаю как сделать чтобы двигалась только стрелка. У меня же двигается само туловище вместе со стрелкой. Вообщем нужно чтобы в прямоугольнике двигалась только стрелка направо, и нечего больше. И не предлагайте центровать элемент, тогда надпись сдвигается вместе со стрелкой.
По большей части css, но если есть вариант как решить на js - предлагайте!

```css
  .button {
   background-color: #fff;
   border: 1px solid black;
   color:black;
   padding: 20px;
   text-align: left;

  }


  .button span:after {
   z-index: 5;
   content: '>';
   opacity: 1;
   transition: all 1s;
  }

  .button:hover span:after {
   opacity: 1;
   padding-left: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<button class="button">Clickme <span></span></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `padding` можно использовать `transform:translateX(20px);`

```css
.button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color:black;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;

}


.button span:after {
  z-index: 5;
  content: '>';
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s;
  display:inline-block;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform:translateX(20px);
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Clickme <span></span></button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое